# Return a set from ajax to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails

I have an `ajax` call which will return a `set<E>`. I need to process this `set` from the JavaScript function from which I call this ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mySr(id){ 
      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '../controller/action',
         data: 'id=' + id,
         success: function(data) {                 
             var length= data.length
             var size = data.size
             alert(data[0]+'----'+length+'--'+size+'----'+data)

         },
         error: function () {
             alert('error')
         } 
     });
    </script>
```

This is the way i used,
The alert will display like this

> ["37",
>   "40","80","90"]----22--undefined----[

I understood the data is clearly reached in the script but i don't know how to iterate through it.
**How to iterate here?

How to get the length?

How to get each elements?**

Comment: How you are actually constructing the response ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the `data`.  Try putting `data = $.parseJSON(data);` after the line `success: function(data) {`

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ for more details.